# cakephp Appmodel access child tables

Tags: database, cakephp, relationship

There are a relationship between Appmodel and child model. Is that mean it can access every database table ? However, i cannot access the child database. Is there any difference with the sytax?

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class CompanyAppModel extends AppModel{


$this->Brand; it works

$this->BrandLangauge;  it does not work


}

class BrandLanguage extends CompanyAppModel {
}
class Brand extends CompanyAppModel {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear the question. But, you can use `ClassRegistry::init` needing to load a model that’s not associated with the current model.

```
$anotherModel = ClassRegistry::init('AnotherModel');
```